# JDK Java EE 7 sem o GlassFish

Tags: java, sdk

Estou tentando instalar o JDK do Java Enterprise Edition e gostaria de saber se tem alguma opção de instalação sem o GlassFish 4, quero usar o TomCat e não o GlassFish, então tem alguma maneira de instalar sem, ou remover só o GlassFish? Ou ele não vai fazer diferença ou influenciar no TomCat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não obstante da instalação do `Glassfish` ocorrer no momento em que instalas o JDK do JavaEE tu podes utilizar qualquer outro Servidor de Aplicação (ou Container) sem a interferência entre eles, desde que garantas que **não tentem utilizar a mesma porta de conexão**(até onde sei, por padrão elas já são diferentes).

Podes sim desinstalar o `Glassfish` como qualquer outra aplicação sem problemas e não haverá problema algum, e tornar a instala-lo como qualquer outro aplicativo.

Comment: Mas como desinstalar somente ele? Porque quando vou desinstalar ele, desinstala o jdk7 tambem.

Comment: Extranho isso! Qual SO utilizas? Se for o `windows`, lá no painel de controle -> Instalar/Desinstalar Programas, e procure pelo Glassfish. Como desinstalas?

Comment: Utilizo o Windows, e no painel de controle não aparece o GlassFish, e o estranho é que o java ainda é instalado no c:\GlassFish4

Comment: Fizeste o download do site da Oracle mesmo? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html

Comment: Sim, neste link mesmo.

Comment: Primeiro baixaste o Java EE e depois o Glassfish?

Comment: Não não, quando se baixa o java_ee_sdk-7u1.zip, nele mesmo já vem o Glassfish.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18038/discussion-between-cold-and-joao-neto).

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que li na págena de downloads o `Java EE 7 SDK` já vem incluido com o `GlassFish` mas, isso não deveria ser motivo de preocupação para ti, visto que a escolha do servidor a ser usado é feita na hora da criação do projecto. So tens que escolher o `Tomcat` na lista de opções.

Comment: Elas utilizam a mesma porta, deixei a porta padrão e ambas estão utilizando a 8080, mas no projeto criei o servidor com o tomcat e encerrei o processo do glassfish. Acho que essa é a unica solução. Acho que não da pda desinstalar somente o glassfish.